# Stop jQuery animation when mouse enters div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div box that changes heights and hides text. In jQuery I have this :

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleDogg6/vovxsrjn/2/)

```
$("#nav_bar").mousedown(function() {
    var mousePos;
    $(this).animate({height: "3.750em"}, 500, "swing");
    $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").show();
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        mousePos = 1;
        $(this).delay(1000).animate({height: "1em"}, 500, "swing");
        $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").delay(1000).hide(250);
        $(this, "#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").mouseenter(function({
            mousePos = 0;
        });
        if(mousePos == 1) {
            $("#nav_bar").animate({height: "1em"}, 500, "swing");
            $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").hide(250);
        } else if (mousePos == 0) {
            $("#nav_bar").stop(true, true);
            $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").stop(true, true);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the animation won't stop when the variable updates and re-enters the box. What I want is the div animation to stop when the mouse re-enter the div.

Comment: Not unbinding nested event handlers is usually problematic to begin with...

Comment: Shikkediel what do you mean? I don't have anything binded (that I can see anyway)

Comment: You do though, you have a `mouseenter` inside a `mouseleave` inside a `mousedown`. So each time that first mousedown is pressed it will create a new instance of the other ones - and they will be remembered, accumulated and triggered accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

It won't stop because out-most function still runs.
Try this:

```
function showBars(){
 $(this).animate({height: "3.750em"}, 500, "swing");
    $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").show();
}

function hideBars(){
 $("#nav_bar").animate({height: "1em"}, 500, "swing");
            $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").hide(250);
}

function animateBox(){
 $(this).delay(1000).animate({height: "1em"}, 500, "swing");
        $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").delay(1000).hide(250);
}

function leaveBox(){
  $("#nav_bar").stop(true, true);
            $("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").stop(true, true);
}

$("#nav_bar").hover(showBars,hideBars);
$("#home, #videos, #about_us, #unknown").hover(animateBox,leaveBox);
```

Pardon me, if syntactical errors.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know